# repositioning elements with media queries

Tags: html, css

I would like to reposition some elements when the size screen changes, exactly like here : http://jsfiddle.net/KAz2u/
I have a logo on the left and a navigation toolbar on the right for wide screens and I want them both to appear on the middle of the page for small screens.

Here is a part of my CSS code

```
.logo{
  width: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 30px;}

nav{
  position: fixed;
  right: 35px;
  top: 50px;
  font-family: "Brown-Regular";
  word-spacing: 3px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 8pt;
  z-index: 1;}

@media(max-device-width: 480px){
.logo{
  position:relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  }

nav{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  word-spacing: 70px;
  }
}
```

And this is at the beginning of my HTML code :

```
<img class="logo" src="pics/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
<nav><a href="index.html">WORK</a>
<a href="mailto:">CONTACT</a> 
<a href="#infos">INFOS</a></nav>
```

Unfortunately it is not working as I want, the elements are not centered, they go a little bit to the left (on mobile phone) I don't see what is wrong.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you want it to work like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max-width` instead of `max-device-width` in the media query

Answer (score 0):

Use `@media screen and(max-width: 480px){`

that should work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15360288)

Comment: it does his media query is incorrect @junkfoodjunkie